# What is causing a SignalR FormatException Invalid Cursor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I have written a simple SignalR hub:

```
public void PostUpdate(string message)
    {
        try
        {
            var update = URS.Tools.JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromJson<DataUpdate>(message);
            switch (update.UpdateType)
            {
                case DataUpdateType.Opportunity:
                    Clients.All.UpdateOpportunity(update.DataUpdateId);
                    break;
                case DataUpdateType.Contact:
                    Clients.All.UpdateContact(update.DataUpdateId);
                    break;
                case DataUpdateType.Client:
                    Clients.All.UpdateClient(update.DataUpdateId);
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Logger.LogError(exception);
        }
    }
```

It is running with a Silverlight 5 client.   For the most part it works, but after 5 - 30 minutes I get an error coming from withing the library:

```
Exception information: 
Exception type: FormatException 
Exception message: Invalid cursor.
at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Messaging.Cursor.GetCursors(String cursor, Func`2 keyMaximizer)
at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Messaging.DefaultSubscription..ctor(String identity, IEnumerable`1 eventKeys, TopicLookup topics, String cursor, Func`2 callback, Int32 maxMessages, IStringMinifier stringMinifier, IPerformanceCounterManager counters)
at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Messaging.MessageBus.CreateSubscription(ISubscriber subscriber, String cursor, Func`2 callback, Int32 messageBufferSize)
at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Messaging.MessageBus.Subscribe(ISubscriber subscriber, String cursor, Func`2 callback, Int32 maxMessages)
at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Infrastructure.Connection.Receive(String messageId, Func`2 callback, Int32 maxMessages)
at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Transports.ForeverTransport.ProcessMessages(ITransportConnection connection, Func`1 postReceive, Action`1 endRequest)
```

When I look at the packets, I cannot see a difference between the one just prior to the error that succeeds and the call that fails.  It is running serverEvents transport, but I tried longPolling to no avail.

The exception is happening in the server.

Any ideas what could be causing the above error and/or how to resolve it?

Comment: That's weird. Are your server and client running the same version of SignalR? Can you create a new project that reproduces this behavior?

Comment: I set up a simple hub and flooded it with messages and got no errors.

Comment: I pointed my stress program to the real server and the error continues to happen in the server.

Comment: Not sure you answered my question.

Comment: I created a new project and cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: File a bug on github with a pointer to the sample project so we can try it and fix the issue.

Comment: If I can create a sample that reproduces the problem I will file a bug.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I did get a workaround going.  If I destroy the connection and re-connect to the server I can let the client continue running and the user is unaware the problem occured.

Comment: Did you create the issue with a sample?

Comment: I got 3800 errors of this on Elmah in 1 hour 5 minutes from 1 user (accessing /signalr/reconnect). Unfortunately, I don't know how to reproduce.